# (1093, u"You can't specify target table 'wallet_consume_record' for update in FROM clause") when using delete in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, sql-delete

I want to delete dulplicate data from MySQL 5.7,this is my sql:

```
DELETE FROM wallet_consume_record 
WHERE trans_no IN (
        SELECT trans_no 
        FROM wallet_consume_record
        GROUP BY trans_no
        HAVING count(trans_no) > 1)
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM wallet_consume_record
    GROUP BY trans_no
    HAVING count(trans_no) > 1
);
```

but when I execute it, it throws:

```
(1093, u"You can't specify target table 'wallet_consume_record' for update in FROM clause")
```

I have already tried:

```
SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';
```

why and how to make it work? I also tried to wrap:

```
DELETE FROM wallet_consume_record 
WHERE trans_no IN (
        SELECT trans_no 
        FROM wallet_consume_record
        GROUP BY trans_no
        HAVING count(trans_no) > 1)
AND id NOT IN (
    select c.id from 
    (
        SELECT min(id) as id
        FROM wallet_consume_record
        GROUP BY trans_no
        HAVING count(trans_no) > 1
    ) as c
);
```

still not work.

```
mysql root@10.244.5.47:meow_report_pro> select version();
+-------------+
| version()   |
|-------------|
| 5.7.29-log  |
+-------------+
1 row in set
Time: 0.001s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't accept refering to the table being updated or deleted in the `from` clause of the same query.

You could express this with a `join` instead:

```
delete w
from wallet_consume_record w
inner join (
    select trans_no, min(id) min_id
    from wallet_consume_record
    group by trans_no
    having count(*) > 1
) w1 on w.trans_no = w1.trans_no and w.id > w1.min_id
```

Comment: still not works:`(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'w\ninner join (\n    select trans_no, min(id) min_id\n    from wallet_consume_recor' at line 1")`@GMB

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GROUP_CONCAT** for it.

Make 2 user defined funcitons which return group concat values of your records and use it in your query.

i.e ( One of the functions would look like )

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_get_tran_no_in_records`()
RETURNS varchar(MAX) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN

declare var_records varchar(10) default '';

SELECT group_concat(trans_no) 
        FROM wallet_consume_record into var_records 
        GROUP BY trans_no
        HAVING count(trans_no) > 1

return var_records;
END
```

And you can simply use it in your query like this

```
DELETE FROM wallet_consume_record 
WHERE trans_no IN (fn_get_tran_no_in_records());
```

You can use same for NOT IN values